# Linq - Matching user claims with record claims

Tags: c#, linq

I have been trying to get my head around how to approach this and I think Linq is probably the way to go, but not sure how.

I have a number of records which each have a number of claims attached to them eg:

- record1

  - claim1
  - claim2
- record2

  - claim1
  - claim4
- record3

  - claim3
- record4

  - claim4

I have a user who has a number of claims:

- user1

  - claim1
  - claim2
  - claim3

I need to match on all of the claims for a record, so in the above example the user record matches record1 and record3

To be clear, as per comments, I want all the records if the user owns all the claims

Can Linq do this ?

Comment: `claim1` is in both `record1` and `record2`?

Comment: @MattBurland - thats right. And could be in record2 and 4 as well.

Comment: so why does `user1` match `record1` and `record3`, but not `record2`.

Comment: Because record2 would require the user to also possess claim4

Comment: Ok, so that's a detail you should make clear in your question. You want all the records if the user owns **all** the claims.

Comment: @MattBurland - Sorry, thought I had. Added your statement to question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to get all records where all of the record's claims are in the collection of claims from this other user.  You can write a LINQ query that more or less reads like those specs:

```
var query = records.Where(record => 
    record.Claims.All(recordClaim => user.Claims.Contains(recordClaim));
```

Note that if `user.Claims` would be a collection of any decent size, and you're executing this in LINQ to objects instead of using a database's query provider, you should put those claims into a `HashSet` first (outside the query), as that will help it scale better.

Answer (score -1):

This is where you would use a [join](http://www.dotnetperls.com/join) statement.

```
var result = from r in records
         join c in user1.claims on r.claims.Contains(c)
         select r;
```

In English, this is saying for every record we have, we are matching records that have at least one claim that matches the user's claims, and returning only those records.  This also assumes you've implemented the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods so you can compare claims.

Comment: That's not a valid `join` syntax in LINQ.